# Using an existing Java oAuth implementation to access the Stack Exchange 2 Api?

Tags: support, api-v2, java, android

I found the [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java) oAuth api and I was wondering how a call would work with the Stack Exchange API, since that uses oAuth.  I'm sorta green when it comes to oAuth but I'm planning on writing an Android app and this is compatible with Android.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange's implementation of OAuth 2.0 is modeled after Facebook's.

While I haven't used Scribe, presumably their [Facebook example is the relevant](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java).